# Azure b2c unauthorized when making api calls in .net5 web api

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I am facing an issue authorizing client apps (users) with azure B2C.
On the backend I have an asp.net5  web api. As for the front-end I am using angular client.
I have registered both apps in my B2c tenants. I've added API Premissions on both apps, also granted admin consents.

Now, when I run the user flow (from the azure portal) and specify the web api in the form, the token works fine, I can make api calls and I get status 200.
However, when tokens are retrieved upon the client app (angular), I get 401 unauthorized response.

My authentication Midleware is configured as follows:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(jwtConfig =>
            {
                jwtConfig.Audience = Configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];
                jwtConfig.Authority = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/tfp/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"]}/v2.0";
                jwtConfig.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                jwtConfig.SaveToken = true;
                jwtConfig.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidAudience = jwtConfig.Audience,
                    ValidIssuer = $"{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"]}/{Configuration["AzureAdB2C:TenantId"]}/v2.0/"
                };
            });
```

Anyone knows what could the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I made some research, and altered the code a little bit, to get more information on what is happening, so I found out that the problem was at the scopes. I was specifying wrong scope name at the client app, therefore I was getting 401 unauthorized.